# How to find sources of connections to Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

In the Mongodb, I can see there are 54 connections from different applications in my local server. Is there anyway to see which one of my applications are using Mongodb more than the others?
Imagine I have 10 application using mongo db with different names and ports.
This is full MongoDB log:

```
2017-09-05T11:04:34.772+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10554 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=s19497827.onlinehome-server.com
2017-09-05T11:04:34.772+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.14
2017-09-05T11:04:34.772+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 08352afcca24bfc145240a0fac9d28b978ab77f3
2017-09-05T11:04:34.772+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-30-223-232 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2017-09-05T11:04:34.772+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-09-05T11:04:34.772+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2017-09-05T11:04:34.805+0430 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover begin
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover lsn: 749244
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover skipping application of section seq:80 < lsn:749244
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover skipping application of section seq:522054 < lsn:749244
2017-09-05T11:04:34.819+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover applying initial journal section with sequence number 749244
2017-09-05T11:04:34.821+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
2017-09-05T11:04:34.821+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2017-09-05T11:04:34.822+0430 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover done
2017-09-05T11:04:34.847+0430 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2017-09-05T11:04:34.847+0430 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2017-09-05T11:04:34.847+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-05T11:04:34.847+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.
2017-09-05T11:04:34.848+0430 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-05T11:04:34.952+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-09-05T11:04:37.040+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55262 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.040+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55264 #2 (2 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.041+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55266 #3 (3 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.042+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55268 #4 (4 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.043+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55270 #5 (5 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.043+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55272 #6 (6 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.043+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55274 #7 (7 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.043+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55276 #8 (8 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.043+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55278 #9 (9 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.044+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55280 #10 (10 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.044+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55282 #11 (11 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.045+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55284 #12 (12 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.046+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55286 #13 (13 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.047+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55288 #14 (14 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.047+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55290 #15 (15 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.058+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55292 #16 (16 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.525+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55324 #17 (17 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:37.870+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55348 #18 (18 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.030+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55360 #19 (19 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.097+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55366 #20 (20 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.527+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55396 #21 (21 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.545+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55398 #22 (22 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.958+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55430 #23 (23 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.964+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55432 #24 (24 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.966+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55434 #25 (25 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.971+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55436 #26 (26 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.993+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55440 #27 (27 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.996+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55442 #28 (28 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.998+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55444 #29 (29 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:38.998+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55446 #30 (30 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.001+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55448 #31 (31 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.002+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55450 #32 (32 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.002+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55452 #33 (33 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.113+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55460 #34 (34 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.132+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55464 #35 (35 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.147+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55466 #36 (36 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.148+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55470 #37 (37 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.616+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55496 #38 (38 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:39.622+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55498 #39 (39 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:40.295+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55540 #40 (40 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:40.351+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55546 #41 (41 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:40.576+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55562 #42 (42 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.106+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55594 #43 (43 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.246+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55608 #44 (44 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.615+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55630 #45 (45 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.621+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55632 #46 (46 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.625+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55634 #47 (47 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.625+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55636 #48 (48 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:41.652+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55638 #49 (49 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:42.300+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55682 #50 (50 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:42.609+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55698 #51 (51 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:42.682+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55702 #52 (52 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:42.979+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55722 #53 (53 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:43.161+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55740 #54 (54 connections now open)
2017-09-05T11:04:43.711+0430 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55780 #55 (55 connections now open)
```

When I run the command:

```
sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP
```

The result is:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.mongobooster-4.0.2-x86_64.AppImage file system /tmp/.mount_XnRJeB
      Output information may be incomplete.
mongod    10082             mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082             mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082             mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082             mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
signalP.g 10082 10083       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
signalP.g 10082 10083       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
signalP.g 10082 10083       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
signalP.g 10082 10083       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
Backgro.k 10082 10084       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
Backgro.k 10082 10084       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
Backgro.k 10082 10084       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
Backgro.k 10082 10084       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10089       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10089       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10089       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10089       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10090       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10090       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10090       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10090       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10091       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10091       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10091       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10091       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10092       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10092       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10092       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10092       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10093       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10093       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10093       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10093       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10094       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10094       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10094       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10094       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10095       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10095       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10095       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10095       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10096       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10096       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10096       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10096       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10097       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    10082 10097       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10097       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    10082 10097       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
WTJourn.F 10082 10098       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
WTJourn.F 10082 10098       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
WTJourn.F 10082 10098       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
WTJourn.F 10082 10098       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
DeadlineM 10082 10099       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
DeadlineM 10082 10099       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
DeadlineM 10082 10099       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
DeadlineM 10082 10099       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
ftdc      10082 10100       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
ftdc      10082 10100       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
ftdc      10082 10100       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
ftdc      10082 10100       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
RangeDele 10082 10101       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
RangeDele 10082 10101       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
RangeDele 10082 10101       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
RangeDele 10082 10101       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
TTLMonito 10082 10102       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
TTLMonito 10082 10102       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
TTLMonito 10082 10102       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
TTLMonito 10082 10102       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
clientcur 10082 10103       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
clientcur 10082 10103       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
clientcur 10082 10103       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
clientcur 10082 10103       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
Periodi.k 10082 10104       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
Periodi.k 10082 10104       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
Periodi.k 10082 10104       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
Periodi.k 10082 10104       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
thread1   10082 10105       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
thread1   10082 10105       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
thread1   10082 10105       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
thread1   10082 10105       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
conn2     10082 10122       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
conn2     10082 10122       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
conn2     10082 10122       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
conn2     10082 10122       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
conn3     10082 10123       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
conn3     10082 10123       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
conn3     10082 10123       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
conn3     10082 10123       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
conn4     10082 10124       mongodb    7u     IPv4              74307        0t0        TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
conn4     10082 10124       mongodb   40u     IPv4             167764        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
conn4     10082 10124       mongodb   41u     IPv4             167765        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
conn4     10082 10124       mongodb   42u     IPv4             167766        0t0        TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: What do you mean by Application? You want to know for particular port or else

Comment: which "mongo server" and which "mongo driver" . you are using?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan anything including port, name that helps, appreciated

Comment: I'm using mongodb 3.4, I don't know what do you mean by mongo driver

Comment: ,As per you log "port 27017" is listening. And it is by default port of mongo db.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945107/is-there-anyway-to-discover-which-ip-addresses-are-connected-to-the-db) answer.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide , Even from "db.serverStatus()" , you can see the connections in mongodb

Comment: @ehsan shirzadi, As you have said " Imagine I have 10 application using mongo db with different names and ports".  what do you mean by "Different name". I mean different application name which are accessing the mongodb or different connection name of the different application.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan For example a python project, Mongobooster application, an so on...

Answer (score 1):

As per your log i am able to see you are using linux O.S.  So, the below grep command you are able to see how connections open to the MongoDB port (27017) on my computer.

```
$ sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP
```

As per you log statement, After execution the above query . which you have already said in your question statement.

I am able to see your log statement like

```
TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52582 (ESTABLISHED)
TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52584 (ESTABLISHED)
TCP localhost:27017->localhost:52586 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I would like to say that here in your case `three connections` open for the mongodb by default port `27017`.

And for the number of connection

```
db.serverStatus()
```

It gives no of connections opend and avail but not shows the connections from which client.

Even you can also get directly by querying

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

for your ref [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/)